# Custom Libraries in Altium not showing components

Tags: altium

After trying in vain to find a normal set of libraries for Altium 17 I decided to make my own custom library for a specific project. I created a new integrated library project in which I then created PCB and schematic libraries. After spending several hours learning how to and creating the footprints and symbols I have arrived a the point where I had several elements in the library.

[image]

I compiled the integrated library but when I tried to use my created symbols the library  displayed only one part (the one that was initially made) :

[image]

Even though, as of now I have three more parts in the same library project. I tried compiling and recompiling the library several times with no result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Off-topic, but not really sure why you use a separate library for every component. Seems a waste of space.

Comment: I have just started using Altium so don't know much. You mean I can create several components in one .schlib/.pcblib file?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying. For example I have 4 generic libraries for schematic parts and 4 generic libraries for footprints: "ICs", "Passives", "Actives", and "Misc". So to clarify, I have "ICs.SchLib" and "ICs.PcbLib". The former holds all of the schematic symbols for all of the ICs I have ever used, and the latter holds all of the PCB footprints for all of the ICs I have ever used. It's called a *library* for a reason - it is a *collection* of parts. Not just one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was confused by different kinds of libraries. The problem is solved, I'd accept your answer if you'd like to write one.

Comment: It's not really an answer, it doesn't solve the problem that you're actually asking about. For what it's worth I don't even use IntLibs. I just use the SchLibs and PcbLibs on their own. This allows me to constantly expand my libraries without having to recompile into an IntLib every time I make a change.

Comment: @DerStrom8, for those of us whose Altium library(ies) are in a sql db & SVN repo, each symbol & each footprint gets its own .SchLib & .PcbLib.  Obviously has its benefits for version-controlling in a multi-engineer environment.

Answer (score 0):

Compile the library before saving. Otherwise Altium will only save changes in your subfiles (in your case LM358_through_hole.SchLib, LM358_through_hole.PcbLib etc) but not add the changes to PSU.LibPkg.

Comment: Done that, still doesn't help..

Answer (score 0):

For now I was able to fix it.

**I just changed also some schematic symbols and compiled the libPkg again.**

If I just add a new footprint without changes in the schematic parts, this new footprint is not shown in my projects. If someone has a explanation to understand this behavior please do not hold you back :-).